# Select <optgroup> Multiple Input in 1 Select

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have 2 foreach in 1 select with different group. I want to change the input from serviceid to domain id if the value is select from 2nd optgroup.

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="serviceid" name="serviceid" required>
   <option disabled selected value> -- Select -- </option>
   <optgroup label="Products">
       @foreach($services['product'] as $service)
           <option value="{{ $service['id'] }}">{{ $service['name'] }}</option>
       @endforeach  
   </optgroup>

   <optgroup label="Domains">
       @foreach($domains['domain'] as $domain)
           <option value="{{ $domain['id'] }}">{{ $domain['domainname'] }}</option>
       @endforeach  
   </optgroup>

</select>
```

Right now output always come with  `"serviceid" => "2"`
i want `"domainid" => "1"` if something is selected from label Domains 2nd array.

Comment: From where you're getting this output? please add the relevant code .

Comment: When user click on submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use hidden inputs for the both cases like the snippet below shows, the you could filter with the non-empty one in your server side code.

Code:

```js
$('#serviceid').select2();

$('#serviceid').on('change', function() {
  var label = $('#serviceid :selected').parent().attr('label');

  if (label == "Domains") {
    $('.domainid').val($(this).val());
    $('.serviceid').val("");
  } else if (label == "Products") {
    $('.serviceid').val($(this).val());
    $('.domainid').val("");
  }

  console.log('domainid=' + $('.domainid').val());
  console.log('serviceid=' + $('.serviceid').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="domainid" class="domainid" />
<input type="hidden" name="serviceid" class="serviceid" />

<select class="form-control select2" id="serviceid" style="width: 300px">
  <option disabled selected value> -- Select -- </option>
  <optgroup label="Products">
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Domains">
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```